# MultiDataTrigger on two DataGrids

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I'm trying to have a button in a disabled state until both DataGrids have at least one selected item. Currently it remains in a Enabled state.

```
<Button MaxWidth="200" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Add" Content="{x:Static UiStrings:Labels.Add}" >
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=EconomicFactors}" Value="-1"></Condition>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=TargetTypes}" Value="-1"></Condition>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Regards,

Comment: Is the button enabled, even if you haven't selected item for both the DataGrids, I mean both datagrids have no selectedItem ?

Comment: The button is enabled and no items have been selected in either DataGrid.

Comment: AS @LPL had pointed out, the MultiDataTrigger works on AND logic so won't fit into your current requirement. But your MultiDataTrigger should work if you have no SelectedItem in both the DataGrid. I tested that on a sample application and got the button disabled until one of the DataGrid has a SelectedItem. Just a comment !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `MultiDataTrigger` all conditions has to be true. I think simplest solution is to replace `MultiDataTrigger` with two `DataTrigger`

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=EconomicFactors}" Value="-1">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=TargetTypes}" Value="-1">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```